# What is the first example of a nation where the first railroad network system was somebody's master plan?

Tags: technology, economy

The background is that I try to understand how complex socioeconomic systems based on a technology mix came in place and how they evolve today.

So I thought of an example, and picked railroads. If I think of railroads, there is actually no "railroad technology", it is rather a complex mix of technological components and services, but still they play together very well as a system.

There had been lots of different approaches, e.g. putting traditional cabs on rails, and all the bits were put together.
But, can we track back a moment where some entity established a strategic development plan before the commercial success of technology (or rather technology mix) was clear? Any type of MVP welcome. But consider who has built the first connection between two cities, might have had and pursued that master plan - or not?

For sure there will be a lot of literature on railroads history, but I do not know whether specifically this aspect has been adressed somewhere.

Comment: Are you asking if someone envisaged the modern transport network that railroads have become before the technology was proved? Also the growth of railroad networks varies by nation so there's probably not a single answer.

Comment: my assumption is that the variety of valid answers here is honestly 0 to 1. Will try to reword.

Comment: So the next question is what's the definition of a "railroad network system"? For, example if I have a railroad that runs between two cities (e,g. Manchester and Liverpool), stopping at a number of stations in between (with goods sidings and engine sheds, etc.), would this be a "railroad network system" for your purposes?

Comment: I would say, it seems to be  kind of MVP  (minimum viable product)  here -
 therefore yes. But consider that maybe smb built a 15 km railroad with two stations and never went for the upscale so it is not a master plan but rather part of the organic process.

Comment: Why would start one an MVP with a whole system? It would be foolish and costly to have some grand plan and built a whole system, while there is no even a working example. Most railways started with a single line between two places. If you are looking for "let build a whole network from birth" you should look for underdeveloped countries, preferably with military dictator or such who could afford a pet project, build a whole grand plan on a technology that proved useful already in other countries.

Comment: then, I am seeking for that company who managed to build that very first single line companies who bought others. If there was one, you know kind of railroad Elon Musk.

Comment: The answer is "no".  Railroads grew organically in most countries. You may wish to check Germany, which may be an exception.   This question would benefit greatly from preliminary research & a clarifying rewite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canada is the country that it is today because the first Prime Minister, John A. MacDonald pushed for the rail to reach from one ocean to the other.  The railroad was the main focus of his agenda.

He capitalized on an uprising in the west in 1885 to demonstrate the value of rail in transporting soldiers.

http://www.canadahistory.com/sections/eras/nation%20building/Railroad.html

Comment: 1885 is well past the point when the "commercial success of technology was clear".

Comment: I had heard at one point that it was felt the country was quite likely to break up if that railroad wasn't built. Most of the population centers are much further away from each other than they are from their nearest large US cities.

Comment: @T.E.D.  Unlike the US, in Canada if you connect the dots between all the concentrated populations centers, you would almost have a single line from coast to coast.

Comment: Did the Right Honorable MacDonald plan the entire rail network, or merely the coast to coast line? (based on your comment, it may not be possible to distinguish between these two.)